# Wordpress : Genesis-Legacy Theme error

Tags: php, wordpress, analytics, genesis

I am getting this error message on some of my pages within worrdpress dashboard.

Google Analytics Stats

> Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in
>   /home/c5280den/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php
>   on line 40
>
> Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in
>   /home/c5280den/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php
>   on line 104

Any help is most appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You should update the plugin, if you've already done this then you can try the following:

FILE - google-analyticator > google-api-php-client > src > Google_Client.php

**OLD CODE (starting at Line 35)**

```
require_once "config.php";
// If a local configuration file is found, merge it's values with the default configuration
if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)  . '/local_config.php')) {
$defaultConfig = $apiConfig;
require_once (dirname(__FILE__)  . '/local_config.php');
$apiConfig = array_merge($defaultConfig, $apiConfig);
```

**NEW CODE (starting at Line 35)**

```
require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . "/config.php");
// If a local configuration file is found, merge it's values with the default configuration
if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)  . '/local_config.php')) {
$defaultConfig = $apiConfig;
require_once (dirname(__FILE__)  . '/local_config.php');
$apiConfig = array_merge($defaultConfig, $apiConfig);
```

Adding to line 35...

```
require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . "/config.php");
```

in place of...

```
require_once "config.php";
```

seems to have fixed the problem.

Get it from here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/recent-update-throws-error-in-settings-page